# How can you pre-define a variable that will contain an anonymous type?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

In the *simplified* example below I want to define `result` before it is assinged.  The linq queries below return lists of anonymous types.  `result` will come out of the linq queries as an IEnumerable<'a> but I can't define it that way at the top of the method.  Is what I am trying to do possible (in .NET 4)?

```
            bool large = true;
            var result = new IEnumerable();   //This is wrong

            List<int> numbers = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}.ToList<int>();

            if (large)
            {
                result = from n in numbers
                             where n > 5
                             select new
                             {
                                 value = n
                             };
            }
            else
            {
                result = from n in numbers
                             where n < 5
                             select new
                             {
                                 value = n
                             };
            }

            foreach (var num in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num.value);
            }
```

EDIT: To be clear I know that I do not need anonymous types in the example above. It is just to illustrate my question with a small, simple example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous types can be declared only with `var`. The good thing is that anonymous types with same properties will be the same types. If you really need it (in this sample you don't need it) then you can write:

```
var result = Enumerable.Repeat(new {value = 0}, 0); // stub value which will give needed type
if (...)
{
    result = ...;
}
else
{
    result = ...;
}
```

P.S.: this was possible even in previous .Net version (lower than 4.0)

Comment: Note that that's "the same property names, with the same property types, in the same order".

Answer (score 1):

You can make it an IEnumerable and just select 'n' in your queries, rather than create an anonymous type. EG:

```
IEnumerable<int> result = null;

result = from n in numbers
         where n > 5
         select n;
```

If what you're actually doing *requires* an anonymous type, then--since you're using C# 4--you can declare `IEnumerable<dynamic> result`, and the rest of your code will work.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question - this is not an anonymous type

Comment: I think the sample code was intended to be illustrative of the goal. If not thought, this is definitely the best way!

Comment: What he's doing in the example doesn't require an anonymous type, but the use of IEnumerable<dynamic> should work if he *does* actually need it.

Comment: But using dynamic has various other downsides, compared with other strongly-typed options.

Comment: Yes that will work in this very simple example but the purposes of me question to know if it is possible to pre define a variable that will contain an anonymous type.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I like Snowbear's answer here if you actually *have* to do this... but personally I would at least *try* to avoid getting into this situation. For example, even *keeping* the anonymous types, I would change your original code to:

```
bool large = true;
var result = new IEnumerable();   //This is wrong

List<int> numbers = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}.ToList<int>();

Func<int, bool> predicate = large ? new Func<int, bool>(x => x > 5)
                                  : x => x < 5;
var result = numbers.Where(predicate)
                    .Select(x => new { value = x });

foreach (var num in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(num.value);
}
```

Note how this has removed duplication - it's clearer that the *only* thing that `large` affects is the predicate.

I find that code ends up being clearer if variables are only assigned a single value, ideally at the point of declaration.

Obviously this isn't always feasible, but it's worth bearing in mind where possible. Where it's *not* possible, Snowbear's answer is fine and guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the type beforehand. E.g.

```
public class TheNumber
{
  public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

....

```
IEnumerable<TheNumber> result;
result = numbers.Where(n => n > 5).Select(n => new TheNumber() { Number = n });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build the LINQ query in parts if you do not need any conditional parts after creating the anonymous type. Otherwise it is probably wiser to define a new struct/class to be used in place of anonymous type.

```
bool large = true;
List<int> numbers = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}.ToList<int>();

IEnumerable<int> query;
if (large) {
    query = query.Where(n => n > 5);
} else {
    query = query.Where(n => n < 5);
}

var result = query.Select(n => new { Value = n });

foreach (var num in result) {
    Console.WriteLine(num.Value);
}
```