# dynamic list in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
if(some condition)
{

       var columnSeries = (from l in logs
       group l by l.MonitoringPorfileName into grp
       select new
       {
                 type = "column",
                 name = grp.Key,
                 data = (from h in Hours
                          let gd = grp.Where(x => x.Hours == h)
                           select gd.Sum(x => x.Count)).ToArray()
                         }).ToList();



           }
}
```

How can i make this variable columnSeries a global variable? i have searched a lot on this, found list dynamic> new{}; but none of them are working so help will be really appreciated

Comment: Whenever you use identation like that, God kills a little kitten.

Comment: What is the condition with `if`?

Comment: does it matters what the condition is? i just want to know how can we make it global so that it can be used after the scope of this IF

Comment: Global variables are bad. Anyway, you can't make anonymous types global. What do you want to do with data that you need it to be global for?

Comment: How global are you wanting the variable to be: To the entire application, to a session, or something else?  There are built in objects that may be useful here like Application or Session as one idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the anonymous type you want a class.

```
public class ColumnSeries
{
    public string type {get; set;}
    //...
}

//class level variable
IEnumerable<ColumnSeries> columnSeries = null;

//then create the ColumnSeries list
columnSeries = (from l in logs
                group l by l.MonitoringPorfileName into grp
                select new ColumnSeries
                {
                   type = "column",
                   name = grp.Key,
                   data = (from h in Hours
                          let gd = grp.Where(x => x.Hours == h)
                          select gd.Sum(x => x.Count)).ToArray()
                });
```

Comment: Even better if you just use IEnumerable<ColumnSeries> instead of List

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an anonymous type inside your if statment but you want to use the result ouside the scope of the if statement.  Usually you just define 'columnSeries' before the if BUT this is an anonymous type so it's not obvous.

So, before the if statement do the following (untested but should be close):

```
var columnSeries = Enumerable.Repeat(new {type="", name="", data=new int[]{0}}, 0);
```

[Check out this question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249870/how-can-you-pre-define-a-variable-that-will-contain-an-anonymous-type)